# How can I stop my activity from being destroyed when I rotate the emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I currently have two activities: MainActivity and DisplayActivity. When I run my application and rotate the emulator, the activities get destroyed. 
How do I make sure that my activity doesn't get destroyed when I rotate the emulator?

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`.

However, I *strongly* discourage this, unless you know what you are doing. Remember that Android allows you to specify different layouts for portrait and landscape orientations. Android decides which layout to use when the Activity is first created (or more correctly, when you call `setContentView()`, which you typically do in your activity's `onCreate()`.) If you override the default behavior of an orientation change, then the Android system will not load the correct layout for you; you will have to implement this yourself. There are probably also other things going on under the hood of which I am unaware, and can cause problems if you don't deal with them yourself.

This means that the preferred way to handle orientation changes is to implement `onSaveInstanceState()` to store any state when your activity is destroyed and restore the state in `onCreate()` when the activity is restarted. See [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) for more details.

Comment: How about `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`?

Comment: @gunar I wasn't aware of that attribute. I have edited my answer to include that information. Thanks.

Comment: @Gunar.  Hack, hack, hack.  To quote Google themselves, "only to be used as a last resort".

Comment: Why is it a hack? There are cases when someone could use that property. Using it wouldn't trigger any code/logic that would define itself as 'hack'.

Comment: @gunar It's probably considered a hack because it bypasses the default behavior and requires the programmer to know what they are doing to not break things.

Comment: Well, considering that, then it's not a hack, but rather an Android recommendation :) ... The programmer ALWAYS needs to know what on Earth he's doing there.

Comment: @gunar Or you can let the Android platform take care of the details without knowing *exactly* what it's doing.

Comment: I tried several examples, but what stopped the activity from being retarted for me on rotate was this, android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" Spicifically the "screenSize" with just "keyboardHidden|orientation" it did not work. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

By default, android will destroy and recreate your activity when there is a big change such as a change in orientation or language. This is actually good. If you do things correctly, the activity's state will be saved and restored so the user won't even know the activity was recreated. In doing so, Android automatically applies any resources that may have changed, such as layouts that only apply to landscape mode.

If you really want to just disable this and manually update any resources that may have changed or stay with the old ones, go ahead and add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to your manifest, within the desired activity. It will no longer be recreated on orientation change.

Comment: +1 For answering the question while cautioning the OP to prefer the default behavior.

Comment: @LeboneMcdonald  I echo the caution.  This is a hack.  There are lots of ways your app will still crash if you do this.  For example, try changing the language.

Comment: It's just way easier to let android handle all the resource updates that come with a orientation change. Sure, you can do it your self by overriding onConfigurationChanged within the Activity, but there's always a chance you could do it wrong. Now, if you only support one language and one layout and one keyboard and plan to do so forever, it may not be that bad to set configChanges. Just make sure you understand what you are doing.